# Matplotlib control which plot is on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am wondering if there is a way to control which plot lies on top of other plots if one makes multiple plots on one axis. An example:

[image]

As you can see, the green series is on top of the blue series, and both series are on top of the black dots (which I made with a scatter plot). I would like the black dots to be on top of both series (lines).

I first did the above with the following code

```
plt.plot(series1_x, series1_y)
plt.plot(series2_x, series2_y)
plt.scatter(series2_x, series2_y)
```

Then I tried the following

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(series1_x, series1_y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(series2_x, series2_y)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3.scatter(series2_x, series2_y)
```

And some variations on that, but no luck.

Swapping around the `plot` functions has an effect on which plot is on top, but no matter where I put the `scatter` function, the lines are on top of the dots.

**NOTE:**

I am using Python 3.5 on Windows 10 (this example), but mostly Python 3.4 on Ubuntu.

**NOTE 2:**

I know this may seem like a trivial issue, but I have a case where the series on top of the dots are so dense that the colour of the dots get obscured, and in those cases I need my readers to clearly see which dots are what colour, hence why I need the dots to be on top.

Comment: Why do you recreate the subplot axes for each new plot? You can just create one subplot then do all your plotting in there (and use the zorder as in the answers below to control which is on top)

Comment: I did mention that I did "some variations" on that which I showed there - I did do it with only subplot too. I normally just do it with plt.plot, plt.scatter, etc. though. I normally do not worry about the axes and figure objects unless I need to pass them around different functions and do all kinds of fancy stuff.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the [zorder kwarg](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_zorder) where the lower the zorder the further back the plot, e.g.

```
plt.plot(series1_x, series1_y, zorder=1)
plt.plot(series2_x, series2_y, zorder=2)
plt.scatter(series2_x, series2_y, zorder=3)
```

Comment: Great, works perfectly. Nice elegant solution. I assume that the `zorder` value defaults to the `zorder` of the previous plot, starting at one? So, say I just do a `plot` (the first one) without `zorder`, that `plot` has `zorder = 1`, the next `plot` (without specifying `zorder`) has `zorder = 2`, etc..?

Comment: Sorry, in my comment above I meant that the "`zorder` value defaults to one plus the `zorder` value of the previous plot..."

Comment: Yes, it looks that way in my testing.

Comment: If you plot on two y-axis, none of these will help you. I find that the `ax` you define second will always be on top of the first. For example in this case: `fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))`, then `ax1 = ax2.twinx()` means `ax1` is always on top and vice versa

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can. Just use `zorder` parameter. The higher the value, more on top the plot shall be.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(series1_x, series1_y, zorder=3)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(series2_x, series2_y, zorder=4)

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3.scatter(series2_x, series2_y, zorder=5)
```

Alternatively, you can do line and marker plot at the same time. You can even set different colors for line and marker face.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(series1_x, series1_y)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2.plot(series2_x, series2_y, '-o', color='b', mfc='k')
```

The `'-o'` sets plot style to line and circle markers, `color='b'` sets line color to blue and `mfc='k'` sets the marker face color to black.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted - it gave the same info as the other (good) answers and also gave a decent alternative.

Comment: @Konrad `Drawing is done per Axes at a time. If you have overlapping Axes, all elements of the second Axes are drawn on top of the first Axes, irrespective of their relative zorder.` See https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html. Thus, this answer is missleading(?).

Answer (score 4):

Another solution besides using zorder, and worth knowing: You can simply plot a scatter of points using the plot command. Something like `plot(series2_x, series2_y, ' o')`. Note the `' o'` with a space means no lines but circle points. This way the order of plotting them on the axes does put them on top.

Comment: This also works, thanks. How would I set the size of the marker if I were to use `plot`? With `scatter`, I just set the `s` parameter to set size.

Comment: For your specific question you can add the argument `markersize = 10` or `ms = 10` (or whatever number you want) to your plot command. The full list of arguments and functionality can be seen here: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot