# python - matplotlib/seaborn: control which plot on top

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

In the graph generated from the codes that I pasted below, lines always show on top of the scatterplot, which is the opposite of what I want. Tried to play around with zorder parameter as suggested by some threads, but no luck at all..
e.g. 
[Matplotlib control which plot is on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781612/matplotlib-control-which-plot-is-on-top)

I had to use seaborn for lineplot because it was easier for me to handle time series with null values.

df has columns index, bid,ask,fillprice,fillsize,mark,color.

```
...

sns.lineplot(df.index,df.bid,ax=ax,color='#d9dbde')
sns.lineplot(df.index,df.ask,ax=ax,color='#d9dbde')


if sum(df.fillsize>0) > 0:

    sizes = 200* df.fillsize / max(df.fillsize)

    for xp, yp, m,c,s in zip(df.index, df.fillprice, 
                             df.mark, df.color,sizes):
        #ax4.scatter([xp],[yp], marker=m,color='red',s=400)
        ax.scatter([xp],[yp], marker=m,color=c,s=100)

    ax.set_ylabel(sym)
```

Comment: How can we run your code in its present form? Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you try `ax.scatter(..., zorder=3)`?